# ¿Como undo poner los atributos de una matriz de objetos a través de un bucle for?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego por consola, este juego quiero que sea de varios jugadores, en función del numero de jugadores creo un array de objetos (jugadores) del tamaño indicado, después quiero añadir el nombre a cada jugador con setName(String) pero lamentablemente no me deja, me salta el siguiente error: **Cannot invoke "Player.setName(String)" because "players[0]" is null**

Como puedo solucionarlo?

aquí os dejo el código:
Class player:

```
private String name;
private String token ;//que muñeco eligen
private int money = 1500;
private int place =0;

//Constructor
public Player(){

}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Main:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Cuantos jugadores van a Jugar? 2-4");
    byte n_players = sc.nextByte();
    Player [] players = new Player[n_players -1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n_players; i++) {
        System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre");
        players[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

---

```
String nombre1 = "Marcos"; players[0].setName(nombre1);
    String nombre2 = "Juan"; players[1].setName(nombre2);
    String nombre3 = "Sara"; players[2].setName(nombre3);
    String nombre4 = "Lucia"; players[3].setName(nombre4);
```

indicando en el scanner que hay 4 jugadores me sigue dando el mismo error

---

```
System.out.println("Cuantos jugadores van a Jugar? 2-4");
    byte n_players = sc.nextByte();
    Player [] players = new Player[n_players -1];
   for (int i = 0; i < n_players; i++) {
        System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre");
       players[i] = new Player();//Linea 13
       players[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

La consola muestra:

```
Cuantos jugadores van a Jugar? 2-4
3
Escribe tu nombre
Escribe tu nombre
Marcos
Escribe tu nombre
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: Player [] players = new Player[n_players] quitale el -1
cuando se crean arreglos pones el total de elementos contados normalmente

Comment: tambien recomiendo que cuando recorra un arreglo siempre use el arreglo.length. Ejemplo for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) asi nunca le va a dar ese error

Comment: Edite la respuesta para que este todo ahi mejor

Comment: genial, muchas gracias

Comment: Si ya con eso lo solucionaste, recuerda poner como aceptada mi respuesta. Suerte!

Comment: Borra esta _no-respuesta_. La zona de respuestas es para respuestas completas a la pregunta, no para agregar más detalles. Debes editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/359767)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que inicializar cada uno de los jugadores.
Creaste una lista de jugadores

```
Player [] players = new Player[n_players];
```

Pero ahora deberias recorrer esa lista y llamar el constructor
para poder despues hacer el setNombre

Aqui te puedo recomendar algo y es que crees un constructor no default donde mandes el nombre, algo como asi:

```
public Player(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Y cuando recorres la lista llamas al constructor que tiene el parametro de name

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre");
    players[i] = new Player(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: además del constructor por defecto también tengo uno con los atributos, probémoslos a eliminar los temas y poner solo String name, pero sigue dando error,

Comment: prueba poniendo player[i] = new Player();

Comment: Acabo de comentar lo que me pone, parece que va mejor encaminado :)